# Angular firestore perform another query from previous query

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I using @angular/fire to query data and I want to saving the firebase cost by reducing the number call of firebase query.

I have 2 function that query from the same collection. First is get all data and second is query with condition. How the second function to query data from the first function so it only call 1 time if firebase query

```
constructor(private _afs: AngularFirestore)
```

function 1 get all data from user

```
this._afs.collection('firebase-user-table').valueChanges().subscribe(data => {
        console.log('User data:', data);
      })
```

function 2 get only which user is_admin is true

```
this._afs.collection('firebase-user-table', (ref) => ref.where(is_admin, '==', true)).valueChanges().subscribe(data => {
        console.log('Admin data:', data);
      })
```

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#use_a_document_snapshot_to_define_the_query_cursor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this using rxjs:

```
let allUsers$ = this._afs.collection('firebase-user-table').valueChanges();

let adminUsers$ = allUsers$.pipe(
map((users) => users.filter(user)) => user.is_admin)
)
```

Then subscribe to each observable as needed